# when the subspace of a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ contained in a ball?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $V$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and $B(a,R)$ represents an open ball in $V$.
I am trying to find all subspaces $W$ of $V$ such that $W \subset B(a,R)$.
I claim that no such subspaces exist. Because if we can find a subspace $W$ in the ball, we can find a small enough ball inside the subspace. But if the subspace contains a ball then this subspace is the whole space $V$.

Is that correct argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ can lie in a ball. For any nonzero vector $w$, you can always find scalar $c$ large enough such that $cw$ lies outside of $B(a, R)$.